# Sending Images and data to PHP server-side

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

It,s my first time trying to send Images & Data to a PHP Server from an app, and I am quite confused as to what's the best way to achieve this.

In my research, I came across [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking) library and [this base64](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/BaseSixtyFour) library (which I would take suggestion in another one), but I don't know if I can achieve what I want with that or how to implement it.

What I want to do is to send data & images that have a relationship.

Lets say the `User` has to upload their `user details + their picture` and their `house details + a picture`
my `JSON` would be something like

```
{
    "userDetails": { "name":"jon",
                  "surname":"smith",
                  "phone":"123412",
                  "userPic":"base64pic"
                },
    "house": { "address":"123 asd",
               "postcode":"w2 e23",
               "housePic":"base64pic"
            }

}
```

of course that `JSON` would also have to include security validations.

My problem comes when I would like to avoid using `base64` encoding given the 33% size increase and I don't know how I could send the same information to PHP.

I get very confused when trying to send images & data that have a relationship and should be stored taking that relationship into account in the server.

Basically What I am looking for is a way to send the same information but not `base64 encoded images` but keeping the relationship in the data and trying to send as fewer request as possible. Is it possible? if so How?

Comment: yes you can easily do that with AFNetworking

Comment: hi @Jonathan i have posted answer for the same in my recent post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084403/uploading-image-via-post-in-objective-c/15477035#15477035), refer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at this example for instance, eveything is pretty self explanatory but ask me if you have any questions

```
-(void) postStuff{
        AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.yourdomain.com/"]];
        NSDictionary *parameter = @{@"body"@"Anything you want to say!"};
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"api/v1/posts/newpost/" parameters:parameter constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
            [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"image" fileName:@"image.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];
        }];
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
        [operation  setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLOG(@"DONE!!!");
        }
        failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLOG(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];
        [httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
}
```