# how to upload a image/video on server using HTTPPost

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, file-upload

I am trying to upload a image on my server but its always returning "**FILE OBJECT is NUll**" means its not receiving the image I am trying to send

I have to upload a image against the input key "**file**"
along-with 2 text parameters "**textParam1**" and "**textParam2**"

I am not getting where i am wrong, here is my code:

```
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"], 90);

// setting up the URL to post to
NSString *urlString = @"http://172.16.16.209:8080/xyz/upload.htm";
NSString *textParam1 = @"10";
NSString *textParam2 = @"ABCDEFGHIGH";

// setting up the request object now
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];


NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

// file
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"testImage\"; filename=\"Default.png\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// text parameter 1
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"textParam1\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[textParam1 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// text parameter 2
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"textParam2\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[textParam2 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// close form
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// set request body
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// now lets make the connection to the web
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"returnString: %@",returnString);
```

where to pass the parameter "**file**" against the image to be uploaded.

the url is running on local eclipse and not accessible outside, but service is working fine in case of android.

Comment: NSString *urlString = @"http://172.16.16.209:8080/xyz/upload.htm";
Bind your parameters in the urlString like this NSString *urlString2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?file=%@&parameter1=%@&parameter2=%@",urlString,parameter1,parameter2];

Comment: Checkout `AFNetworking` framework. There are many convenience methods for uses like this: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.

Comment: I have posted answer for it before some time to upload file/image to server. [Find Post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084403/uploading-image-via-post-in-objective-c/15477035#15477035)

Answer (score 0):

> You should take a look at ASI frameworks
>   http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/