# Wrong multipart - POST on the server (json + image)

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, rest, multipart

The server does not see parts of the "token" and "name+_time"

My code

```
NSArray *keysParams = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"time",nil];
NSArray *valuesParams = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:time, nil];
NSDictionary *dictParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:valuesParams       forKeys:keysParams];

NSError *writeError = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictParams options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&writeError];


NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(getImage1, 0.8);
NSString *boundary = @"&&3rewfwefwfewfhufrbewfuweriwefr";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

//this appends the image
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"photo.jpg\"\r\n",fileName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
//json
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@_time\" \r\n",fileName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:jsonData];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
//token
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"token\" \r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[token dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
```

request body

```
imagename(file)
/imagename_time/ - part name
{
time:100
}
/token/ - part name
"string"
```

I have a bug somewhere, but I can not find it. I write for the first time multipart post.
Thanks!

Comment: You did not mention what is the bug??

Comment: Well obviously your statement "Everything is written correctly" is false, or else you wouldn't be having this problem.

Comment: @SantaClaus, Yes, there is a bug. I can not find it.

Comment: @hussainShabbir My bug "Token not send" and "part _time" not found

Comment: refer my answer to upload image on server, [Refer post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084403/uploading-image-via-post-in-objective-c/15477035#15477035) Good Luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. My fail in the wrong "boundary"

Working code:

```
//  image
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"photo.jpg\"\r\n",fileName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//  json
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@_time\" \r\n\r\n",fileName"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", jsonString] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//  token
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"token\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[token dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// close form
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];
```

Thank you for your answers to my question =)

Comment: I am also having same problem and could not resolve with your solution, What was the problem with "boundary" you mention.