# Upload Image in to server

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch, image-uploading

This my code from this link

[Uploading Image via POST in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084403/uploading-image-via-post-in-objective-c)

```
// COnvert Image to NSData
NSData *dataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_chosenImage, 1.0f);
NSLog(@"%@", dataImage);
NSString *tempURLString = [APIStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"***" withString:@"upload"];

// set your URL Where to Upload Image
NSString *urlString = @"My URL String";

// set your Image Name
NSString *filename = @"My File Name";

// Create 'POST' MutableRequest with Data and Other Image Attachment.
NSMutableURLRequest* request= [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
NSLog(@"%@", request);
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];    
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"my_upload_file_name\"; filename=\"%@_.jpg\"\r\n", filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSLog(@"%@", postbody);
[postbody appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:dataImage]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:postbody];

// Get Response of Your Request
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Response  %@",responseString);
```

This code not working for me.. I'm getting failed message. Is any wrong in my code.

And i tried this code also

https://jmsliu.com/3241/select-and-upload-multiple-photos-from-gallery-or-camera-in-ios.html

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

_chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
   [self uploadImageLegacy:_chosenImage];
}


- (void) uploadImageLegacy:(UIImage *)image {
NSString *tempURLString = [Str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"***" withString:@"upload"];
//upload single image
NSURL *url = @"My URL here";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:5.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *POST_BODY_BOURDARY = @"SportuondoFormBoundary";
NSString *contentTypeValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", POST_BODY_BOURDARY];
[request addValue:contentTypeValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];

NSMutableData *dataForm = [NSMutableData alloc];
[dataForm appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",POST_BODY_BOURDARY] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[dataForm appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"param1\";\r\n\r\n%@", @"10001"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.9);
[dataForm appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",POST_BODY_BOURDARY] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[dataForm appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"my_upload_file_name\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", @"test"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[dataForm appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[dataForm appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];

[dataForm appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",POST_BODY_BOURDARY] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:dataForm];
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didSendBodyData:(int64_t)bytesSent totalBytesSent:(int64_t)totalBytesSent totalBytesExpectedToSend:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToSend {
NSLog(@"Sent %lld, Total sent %lld, Not Sent %lld", bytesSent, totalBytesSent, totalBytesExpectedToSend);
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition))completionHandler {
_receiveData = [NSMutableData data];
[_receiveData setLength:0];
completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseAllow);
NSLog(@"NSURLSession Starts to Receive Data");
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
[_receiveData appendData:data];
NSLog(@"NSURLSession Receive Data");
}

 - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {
NSLog(@"URL Session Complete: %@", task.response.description);

if(error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error %@",[error userInfo]);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Uploading is Succesfull");

    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_receiveData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", result);
}
}
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: I'm not getting any error, I'm getting upload failed message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this code and working for me

```
    NSMutableDictionary* _params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [_params setObject:[UserDict valueForKey:@"userid"] forKey:@"userid"];
    // YOU CAN ADD YOUR  PARAMETERS HERE


    NSString *BoundaryConstant = @"----------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy";
    NSString* FileParamConstant = @"file";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", BoundaryConstant];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    //    NSData *bodyData = [appData createFormData:_params withBoundary:BoundaryConstant];
    for (NSString *param in _params) {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [_params objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
    // I AM RESIZING IMAGE YOU CAN SKIP
    UIImage *newSizeImage = [self imageWithImage:currentlyCapturedImage scaledToSize:newImageSize];

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newSizeImage, 1.0);

    if (imageData) {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image%@.jpg\"\r\n",FileParamConstant, timestamp] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:imageData];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

now You have `body` with your parameters and image.

You can use this as body of request `[request setHTTPBody:body];`

and call the service

Hope it will helpful

**EDIT**

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

}];

[postDataTask resume];
```

Comment: @iOS  Make sure you change  this         `[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image%@.jpg\"\r\n",FileParamConstant, timestamp] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];` according to you

Comment: What is _params userid

Comment: @iOS  it is example. you can put your parameter that need to pass in request with image

Comment: @iOS are you sending any parameter to server  along with image ? then use `_params`  dictionary as per my example

Comment: Yes I'm sending multiple parameters along with url

Comment: @iOS for example if you are sending name parameter. then  use like     `[_params setObject:@"Prashant" forKey:@"name"];`

Comment: ok, I understood thank you..., but can you please implement this with NSURLSession task.

Comment: @ Prashant Tukadiya, Thank you very much to spent your valuable time for me... I tried but I'm getting the same message failed. So we check server side code after that I will try once again and I will inform you.

Comment: @ Prashant Tukadiya, with out doing any changes in server side my image uploaded successfully...Thank you very much...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165806/discussion-between-ios-and-prashant-tukadiya).