# Obj-c: How do I capture an image in an iOS app programmatically and push it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, screenshot, image-capture

My app (iOS obj-c) displays a graph that tracks a user's breath during a test. When the test is complete, I want to send an image of the graph to a database. How do I capture the graph as an image from the app display, and how do I push an image using POST?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214957/how-do-i-take-a-screen-shot-of-a-uiview ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084403/uploading-image-via-post-in-objective-c ?